# Failed to load Amazon Mobile Ads

Tags: java, android, mobile, ads, amazon-mobile-ads

I cant receive any testing Ads with the Amazon test app "package com.amazon.sample.interstitialad;".
I have implemented Amazon Mobile Ads in accordance with this guide: https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/mobile-ads/docs/quick-start

Amazon informed me 10 days ago that my tax identity has been validated.

This is my Logcat log:

```
AdRegistration: Debug logging has been enabled.
AdRegistration: Amazon Mobile Ads API Version: 5.9.0
AdRegistration: Test mode has been enabled.
...
ResponseReader AdRequest WebRequest HttpURLConnectionWebRequest: Response Body: {"noretryTTL":10,"instrPixelURL":"https://aax-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/x/px/p/Qgqh65RdKQWxvus1GfxuG2UAAAFwTmMIggMAAA-iA90O6sw/","errorMessage":"no results","errorCode":"503","status":"error"}
MetricsCollector: METRIC Publish AD_NO_RETRY_TTL_RECEIVED
AdLoader: Server Message: no results. Try again in 10 seconds; code: 503
...
Ad failed to load. Code: NO_FILL, Message: Server Message: no results. Try again in 10 seconds
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

NO_FILL Means current no ads available to show.
You can try VPN & select US country to check ads are working or not.
you are using old sdk new version is available which is amazon-ads-6.0.0.jar

for help you can checkout this full integration video -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mBMRQUEmdU